# Reputation lost without showing any log when answered using a VPN connection

Tags: support

I lost some of my reputation. Also one of my answers is not shown in the answers tab. I used to work on a remote machine using [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (Amazon US IP address). Sometimes I log in to Stack Overflow using the same VPN connection. Does that make me an unauthorized user? [My Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300034/arun-killu?tab=answers).

I don't have a proof actually, because there isn't any log of deleting nor is the answer shown in my Stack Overflow answer tab. I got the link to question from recent deletes, [HTML to JS Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016395/html-to-js-object/20016455#20016455).

Comment: There are two questions here; one about rep loss (possibly due to a deleted answer), another about logging in over a VPN.

Comment: Please be more specific. What SE site? What answer? What happened exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely answer of yours was deleted.

Go to your profile, go to your answers tab and in the bottom you'll see "deleted recent answers" link. Click it to see list of answers you wrote that were deleted recently.

If you don't see any links, or such link leads to Page Not Found, it means a question you answered was deleted, deleting your answer as well as a result.

In case your answer was deleted directly you'll see by whom and maybe a comment explaining why and you can flag it, choose Other and ask to undelete.

In case it's part of deleted question post link here and 10K users can give more details.

Comment: But does Vpn connection make me a suspicious user ?

Comment: @ArunKillu no, it's totally not relevant. Did you find the deleted answer?

Comment: Yes this is the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016395/html-to-js-object/20016455#20016455

Comment: @ArunKillu the question itself was closed as off topic seven hours ago and deleted by a moderator four hours ago. Nothing wrong in your answer. It was deemed off topic because it's very specific to "handlebars", so it probably fits its support forums and not Stack Overflow which is meant for general programming questions.

Comment: oh..I saw some comment for closing ok, thankyou for the followup and feedback .

Comment: @ArunKillu yeah, with 3K yourself you can see pending close votes and even cast your own. :)

Comment: @ArunKillu I undeleted and reopened that question since it wasn't, in fact, asking for resource recommendations. You should see the reputation gained from the upvotes on your answer returned to you soon.

Comment: @AnnaLear thank you for that. You saved my 10 rep as well :-) (not because I care for the rep, but the closevotes and deletion really surprised me.